# windows clearmake parallel build with dependency

Tags: makefile, clearcase

I have a situation where I am building something like this:

```
target1: dep1 list2

dep1:
     perl script that generates a .h file

list2:
     compiles a list of c files 
     including one that needs the .h file from dep1 to exist
```

I build `target1` with a parallel build option (`-J 6`) and I am trying to understand the `clearmake` Makefile syntax that would say "finish `dep1` and then do all of `list2` compiling in parallel".
Whenever I build, it fails to compile items in `list2` because the header file generation hasn't happened yet from `dep1`, because they are all happening in parallel (`dep1` takes like 20 seconds).

How would you avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

One way to introduce sequential build steps in a clearmake is to split that build in two, a bit like what is explained in the section "[Coordinating reference times of several builds](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_build_unix.doc/pointers_on_using_clearcase_build_tools.htm)":

> An alternative approach is to run all the builds within the same `clearaudit` session.
>   For example, you can write a shell script, `multi_make`, that includes several invocations of `clearmake` or `clearaudit` (along with other commands).
>   Running the script as follows ensures that all the builds are subsessions that share the same reference time:

```
clearaudit -c multi_make
```

While the clearaudit part might not be relevant to your case, the main idea persist: pilot the build process through *multiple* sequential `clearmake` steps, instead of trying to code those steps in the Makefile (with the `.NOTPARALLEL:` directive mentioned in [clearmake Makefiles and BOS Files](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_build_unix.doc/clearmake_makefiles_and_bos_files.htm)).

Comment: I see what you mean, perhaps i can recursively call the clearmake  several times passing the -J to only the targets that can be parallel. the initial clearmake call can be made  with no -J..  i will look into doing that..  I also  see the warning belowwhen i am building with -J..  do you understand this "target group" concept and what the syntax actually would be?:  Rules with multiple targets may not build correctly in parallel,
unless they are declared as a 'target group', like this:
        a + b:
or as patterns in GNU compatibility, like this:
        %.a %.b:

Comment: @DanielScire I don't have enough experience with "target group", which is why I prefer simplifying the process by making smaller steps, and making sure they run in the proper order.

Comment: ok it worked, i rearranged things so there are 2 targets.. now clearmake with no -j option for the 1st target, Inside the makefile, i am recursively calling clearmake again with the -j for the target that can be built in parallel..   Thanks for the idea!